# Exclude items in array in Where-Object

Tags: arrays, powershell, where-clause

I was wondering if there is a simple/single-line way of excluding an array of things using `Where-Object`.

So rather than go:

```
 $filtereddata = $data |
     Where {$_.var -ne "1"} |
     Where {$_.var -ne "2"} |
     Where {$_.var -ne "3"} |
     Where {$_.var -ne "4"} |
     Where {$_.var -ne "5"} |
     Where {$_.var -ne "7"} |
     Where {$_.var -ne "10"} |
     Where {$_.var -ne "12"}
```

I go

```
 $filterddata = $data | Where {??????}
```

Or something like that...

Notice that they are all the same `.Var`.

Is there a way of doing this more simply? Especially say if, in an automated scenario, the number of *Var* to be excluded is ever growing?

Comment: PS3+: `$data | where var -notin $exclude` where $exclude is an array of strings.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked ... `$data | where {$_.var -notin $array}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$filtereddata = $data | Where{ $_.var -notin 1..12 }
```

You could use `-notin` with the `..` array notation if your numbers are actually integers and not strings.

Otherwise you could have single where with multiple conditions joined with `-or` rather than piping to lots of additional where-object commands.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't remember  of the correct usage of the *-notin*, that worked really well .... with the code `$data | where {$_.var -notin $array}`

Comment: Note that `-notin` isn't available prior to PowerShell v3. In older versions use `1..12 -notcontains $_.var` instead.